# the 500 state http error represents a sqli vulnerability?

Tags: sql

I have a login form with its respective user field and password, I was trying to prove if the page is vulnerable to sqli, and try to generate some type of error by entering character combinations, and none generated any errors (apparently the inputs were well sanitized by filtering special characters), but curiously when I enter the% symbol in the password field and in the user field I add any word, this gives me a status error 500 (http 500 Error in the internal server), all I discovered this thanks to the BurpSuite tool, all the data is sent using the post method, so I discovered that error through BurpSuite, and obviously the browser does not show that error, the only thing that is displayed in the browser is a message saying that the user and / or password are incorrect, but internally the server responds with a http 500 and also to not expose errors like this to the client it shows a personalized error message (the administrator of the page had to elaborate a personalized error message so as not to expose that type of errors to the client).

Try to make it as understandable as possible, I would like to know if it is correct what I think about that if that http 500 error represents an sqli vulnerability, I think that since that error is occurring when consulting the username and password, but I would like Someone to tell me if I'm wrong or not. Thank you

Comment: I don't think a 500 is a vulnerability as the server refuses (even through crashing the program) to answer / process the request.

Comment: And what else is an error http 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error code 500 does not mean that there is a SQLi vulnerability with the specific input but it also does not mean that there is no such vulnerability.

The error might have been caused by sending some SQL statement to the database and then stumbling over the answer of the database. But it might also have been caused by earlier processing, i.e. before anything was sent to the database. And it might also be that the input sent to the database, caused no harm there but that it caused an error later in the application.

Thus, it points out a potential problem and is probably worth investigating further. But this problem does not need to be at the SQL layer.